# Trouble Implementing Login Form in Asp.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, authentication

I am looking to implement an mvc asp.net application. I have created a login form for the same. Now the login form has its own css stylesheet. how do i make my login form use the css sheet. in asp.net mvc???? Have been breaking my head over this. anyone there can lend me some help would be great???

Comment: post both your login action and login.cshtml here

Comment: what about adding the link to the style sheet on your view? That looks obvious and easy